# vector(vector<double>) only makes even indices

Tags: c++, c++11

I try to generate a dynamic matrix with "max_step" rows and "degree" columns.
But the indices of the vector elements are not 0,1,2,3....max_step.

I always get 0,2,4,...max_step.

If I want to (logical) access line 3, I'll get (of course) an error (free() invalid pointer) or similar.

```
vector<double> qd_algorithm(const std::function<vector<double>()>& poly, const unsigned int max_steps, const unsigned int degree)
{
   vector<vector<double>> e(max_steps, vector<double>(degree+1));

   for (unsigned int i=0;i<max_steps;i++)
   {
       e[i][0]=0;
       e[i][degree+1]=0;
   }
   //stop point debugging
   return poly(); //just for trying

}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
e[i][degree+1]=0
```

You're trying to assign an element past vector's end. `degree` is the last valid index for `e[i]`.

Comment: im dumb, omg ty...but if I have a look on my watchlist while debugging its still displays even indicies, even though e.g: std::cout << e[3][0]; is working :)

Answer (score 0):

In C++ and most langages, we start counting from 0.
So if you have X element in a vector you can access to X - 1 at max.

E.g : 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
That's 5 elements

Here:

```
   e[i][degree+1]=0;
```

You go too far. If you want the last element in the second [] part, access like that :

```
   e[i][degree]=0;
```